# Jquery multiple function with same variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` function:

```
$('.obj').on('mouseenter', function(){
    var obj_top = $(this).offset().top,
        obj_max = obj_top + 10;
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    var obj_top = $(this).offset().top,
        obj_max = obj_top + 50;
});
```

Since it all happens within the same object, is there anyway I can reuse the `obj_top` variable throughout the functions without having to duplicate it?

Comment: downvoter care to comment?

Comment: two events are there so if you want to use first one `mouseenter` then you can use a global variable and update it.

Comment: @Popnoodles this question does not show any research effort and it's not useful

Comment: @Hacketo though much better than 80% of the questions here....

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @GEspinha is there only one element that this affects?

Comment: @Popnoodles we can use a .each() loop and use the logic you proposed - ie loop through each `obj` and create a variable for each one

Comment: Yes you're right @ArunPJohny but the method you posted is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't because those variables are local to the function scope in which they are declared unless you declare it in a shared scope.

But if you don't want to repeat it again then you can use a single event handler for both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and check the `event.type` to see which is the event that caused the trigger based on that decide on the value to be added to the `obj_top` to find out `obj_max`

```
$('.obj').hover(function (e) {
    var obj_top = $(this).offset().top,
        obj_max = obj_top + (e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 10 : 50);
});
```

Comment: @GEspinha For clarity `$('.obj').hover(function` is the same as `$('.obj').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function`

Comment: I guess this solution is much simpler and easy to understand, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

By moving it into a function?

```
$('.obj').on('mouseenter', function(){
    setVariables(this, 10);
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    setVariables(this, 50);
});

setVariables = function(sourceElement, amount) {
    var obj_top = $(sourceElement).offset().top,
        obj_max = obj_top + amount;
}
```

EDIT:  Arun P Johny is right, fixed the faulty "this" reference

Comment: may have to fix `this` reference

Comment: Btw this is not a re-use of `obj_top` variable. Only re-use of function